# Add new clients in the runtime to telegram bot script using telethon in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

I have a telegram bot script using telethon library.

Currently it is running for one client only (telethon_client). But i want to run it for multiple number of clients. But number of clients are not fixed.

Whoever adds (other users) their credentials, bot should work for that account too. This neans new client should be created for that account.

But after `telethon_client.run_until_disconnected()` bot is continuously working.

I tried threads but i could not manage to work it for dynamical number of clients. I can run for 2-5 clients but i dont know how many clients will be added here. Number of clients can change over time.

How can i make it work for that?

Can anyone give me a help how can make it work for that purpose?

Thanks in advance.

```
try:
    telethon_client = TelegramClient(StringSession(SESSION), APP_ID, API_HASH)
    telethon_client.start()
    info("Telethon client connection have been set successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"ERROR - {e}")
    error(f"Telethon client connection error. Error: {e}")
    exit(1)

@telethon_client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=outgoing, incoming=True))
async def handler(event):
    # THERE ARE SOME CODE HERE

telethon_client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Please use the correct terminology. Seems like you are creating a custom **client**, not a **bot**. Also, 'i want to run it for multiple user', what do you want to run? A bot always runs for 'multiple users', and a client can never act as multiple clients at the same time. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You're not forced to use `run_until_disconnected`. The library does not care what you do as long as the `asyncio` event loop is running.

This means you can write other logic you may need to achieve your goal without having to "block" there.

[The `asyncio` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) is a good place to learn what is possible and how to run multiple tasks at once (as well as other questions asked on this site).